# Find Closest Beacon in every second by using RSSI in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, clbeacon

In Stack Overflow, I've seen answer to find closest beacon ([Swift find closest Beacon by rssi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834641/swift-find-closest-beacon-by-rssi/56806475#56806475)).

Here I tried with accuracy to find closest in Objective-C. My app finds beacon in every sec that time accuracy is not working finding closest properly. As he said RSSI will update in every 1 sec. So I'd like to filter closest beacon using RSSI. I converted your Swift code into Objective-C but it's not working fine.

Here is Swift code:

```
//Swift code
var closestBeacon: CLBeacon? = nil
for beacon in beacons {
    if beacon.rssi < 0 && closestBeacon != nil && beacon.rssi > closestBeacon!.rssi {
        closestBeacon = beacon as? CLBeacon
    }
}
```

Here is Objective-C code I converted not working:

```
CLBeacon *closest = nil;

for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {

    if (beacon.rssi < 0 &&  closest != nil && beacon.rssi > closest.rssi) {

        closest = beacon;

    }
}
```

Here please make me perfect where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You need to set assign a value to `closest` at some point before your loop or it will always be `nil` and the `if` will never be true

Comment: @P4yam, I've approved your edit, but see my subsequent edit for how to do proper code formatting.

Comment: I think that you could use `max(by:)` to find the Beacon with the max value, and the compare it with yours saved beacon if exists to set it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in both versions of code as @paulw11 suggests.  Since I wrote that bug in response to another question here is a fix:

Swift

```
var closestBeacon: CLBeacon? = nil
for beacon in beacons {
    if closestBeacon == nil || beacon.rssi < 0 && beacon.rssi > closestBeacon!.rssi {
        closestBeacon = beacon as? CLBeacon
    }
}
```

Objective-C

```
CLBeacon *closestBeacon = nil;

for (CLBeacon *beacon in beacons) {

    if (closestBeacon == nil || beacon.rssi < 0 && beacon.rssi > closest.rssi) {

        closestBeacon = beacon;

    }
}
```

I fixed the bug in the original post, too.

Comment: let me try and comeback to you. Here in your answer closestBeacon is beacon? or need to take another CLBeacon property. Otherwise compiler throws error.

Comment: I edited the answer.  To be consistent with the swift version, I have named the variable closestBeacon